# Jest and ESLint: Expect must have a corresponding matcher call

Tags: javascript, jestjs, eslint

I'm getting an ESLint error `Expect must have a corresponding matcher call - jest/valid-expect` on the first line in this loop where I'm checking for the matching regex (`.toMatch`).

```
const dateRegex = /^([1-9]|1[012])[- \\/.]([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \\/.](19|20)\d\d/

expect(getPerformancePerUserPerDay(input).forEach((item, index) => {
  expect(item['Date']).toMatch(dateRegex)
}))
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong since the usage seems to be correct per their [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tomatchregexporstring). Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first `expect` is not asserting anything, and according to the `jest/valid-expect` rule `Ensure expect() is called with a single argument and there is an actual expectation made.` this triggers an error.
Change to:

```
getPerformancePerUserPerDay(input).forEach((item, index) => {
  expect(item['Date']).toMatch(dateRegex)
})
```